# Вопрос по flexbox для RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

У меня есть RecyclerView. Я добавил библиотеку от Google на Flexbox и сделал так:

```
list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_review__list);
FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager();
flexboxManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
flexboxManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
flexboxManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
list.setLayoutManager(flexboxManager);
```

В результате получается так (не буду здесь писать, как конкретно делал RecyclerView, это не суть важно):

[image: FlexBox]

Суть в том, что я пробовал как и `JustifyContent.FLEX_START`, так и `JustifyContent.CENTER`, но результат не такой, какой я бы хотел.

Мне надо сделать примерно так, как это реализовано в Google Keep

[image: Google Keep]

Как это сделать?

---

Если попробовать использовать `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, возникает проблема: последняя карточка попадает в крайний правый столбец, а надо, чтобы было слева

[image: Проблема]

Comment: Попробуйте стандартный `StaggedGridLayoutManager`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал, но там есть одна проблема, добавил её в вопрос

Comment: Вам придётся с этим смириться. Ну или переписать `StaggedGridLayoutManager` для получения нужного вам поведения. Думаю, за неделю вы справитесь если у вас большой опыт в программировании под андроид

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в том то и дело, что не очень большой

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с другой стороны, как же тогда это реализовано в Google Keep?

Comment: Я думаю, что в `Google Keep` всё ровно так как у вас получилось реализовано. Если нет - вы можете их приложение декомпилировать и посмотреть как оно там сделано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поколдовал над `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, в итоге получилось всё хорошо. А `Flexbox` в этом случае лучше не использовать.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[image: StaggeredGridLayoutManager]